# How to get browser sessionId using Selenium webdriver

Tags: php, yii, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium webdriver (php-webdriver-bindings Yii extension) and I'm trying to get the browser sessionId (the one that the test will be using).  I thought I could get this through webdriver, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  Webdriver has a sessionId, but that is not the one the test browser is using.

I'm trying to login prior to the test running to allow my tests to be an authenticated user which will allow them to access the pages I'm testing.

I've been researching and testing this for a few days now and I'm at a loss.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The class RemoteWebDriver has a getSessionId() method but I am sure that is not what your looking for.  I was trying to do a pure WebDriver project and also noticed that WebDriver didn't have this method.  I'm not sure what the "WebDriver method" for this is...

Comment: I'm not 100% clear as to what you need based off your question, but the method .hashCode() shows the unique hashcode of the Webdriver, and it's been suiting my needs.

Answer (score 5):

You can cast to a concrete type, e.g. [RemoteWebDriver, which they all inherit from, and also implements getSessionId](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html#getSessionId%28%29):

```
((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getSessionId()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Java, but on closer examination of the source code, noticed that the driver I was using was instantiated as a `WebDriver` object. After changing it to a `RemoteWebDriver` object, the `.getSessionId()` method was exposed, and `driver.getSessionId()` returned the session id as expected.

I'm not sure how that would translate to PHP, but I'd recommend going back and checking to ensure that your driver is a `RemoteWebDriver` object, rather than a `WebDriver` object.